# Requests -- How to resolve [Response 404] in requests.get(url, header)?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am getting output as `<[Response 404]>` upon running 
`page = requests.get(article_url, headers=headers_)
    print(page)` command. What are the possible errors and how may I resolve them?

Comment: please,edit your question and show more details about your code

Answer (score 0):

> ### From wikipedia
>
> The HTTP 404, 404 Not Found and 404 error message is a Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) standard response code, in computer network communications, to indicate that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

by doing `print(page)` you're not going to get much information, because page is a **Response** object, and, my guess is, you want to look at some of the attributes of that object (the reply body, the reply status code, etc..)

To do that - use methods described in the requests documentation at
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response

For example you could look at the actual reply body by doing `page.text()`